# Cocoa code- How to see a created folder in iPhone's Document?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

As iam a newbie in iPhone app development, please help me with this issue. 
According to my code, iam trying to create a folder called "New Folder" in the Documents. When i run this code, iam able to get the output in NSLog with the complete path and i can see where the folder is getting created in my system as well. But the problem is iam not able to see this folder in iPhone simulator. Is there any way to see this folder which i have created in simulator?

```
NSArray   *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,       NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSLog(@"%d",[paths count]);
NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/New Folder", documentsDirectory];
NSLog(@"Path is: %@",filePath);
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSLog(@"%d",[manager createDirectoryAtPath:filePath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil]);
NSLog(@"Folder created");
```

Comment: what is the way you use to see the folder in iPhone Simulator?

Comment: @Shekhar Gupta: Iam getting an error with this statement: if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:root isDirectory:YES] == NO) // Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'BOOL *' with an rvalue of type 'signed char'.

Comment: @Sachin: What is the way in the sense?

Comment: Means Are you finding these folder with the help of code or manually you are going iPhone simulator folder?

Comment: i want to see the folder manually in simulator.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can see this folder by going through the following steps....

Open Your **Finder** Window. Go to **Library** -> **Application Support** -> **iPhone Simulator** -> Choose the type of Simulator(like **6.1, 5.0** etc) - > **Applications** -> Check the project of the simulator by its **Name** after going into the numbers -> **Document**.

This is your **Document Directory**. You will find your files here.

[image]

Comment: yes like this i saw the folder, but how to see the same folder in iPhone simulator?

Comment: If you mean literally you can't see it in the iphone simulator... What you can do is just access it using the code programmatically and show the contents likewise.....

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can get all the folders i have created and display them on textview. But unfortunately iam still not able to see them in iPhone simulator.

Comment: @vanya what do u actually want ? U want to see them in ur simulator as wat ?

Comment: i want to see them as folders.

Comment: Ok. Now i want to know if we can get the path of other folders like media, root, library and tmp. Because i want to access the images which are inside media-> DCIM->100APPLE. Please tell me if there is any way for this and help me out with this issue.

Comment: Yes you can get the paths ... You just have to provide the full path till you want to access....

Answer (score 1):

For more simplicity for viewing folders in document directory follow the steps:

1) NSLog the path and then copy it from console.

2) Open finder press Command+shift+g

3) Paste the path and press go.

Answer (score 0):

You can see folder created manually by using following steps :

1. Go to Finder Window
2. Select Application Support
3. iPhone Simulator
4. Now, Select simulator version (say 6.1)
5. Applications (contains list of application that are executed)
6. Select your Application folder
7. Documents contains user created folders.

This is shown in screenshot

[image]